# Структурно-семантическая характеристика

Tags: синтаксис

"Джон купил его уже бывшим в употреблении, за тридцать тысяч". Сказуемое - "купил", "его" -дополнение, а каким членом предложения является "бывшим в употреблении, за тридцать тысяч" - определением или обстоятельством? Или входит в сказуемое? Или ситуант? Непонятно.

Comment: Начальное положение подлежащего-субъекта требует окончания им.падежа даже при инверсии, так как смысловой приоритет остаётся за подлежащим.-это? Оно же есть в настоящем Вашем вопросе. Я убрала комментарий, а то люди не поймут, что это мы здесь упражняемся.

Comment: нужно как то по-русски сказать выражение (но даже при инверсии фактор остается тем же (постановка подлежащего в начале предложения) дело в том ,что буквальный перевод подлежащего -слово,которое стоит в начале предложения-المبدأ

Comment: Вы уверены, что перевод таков - слово, которое стоит в начале предложения, а не "слово,занимающее главное положение"? Начало - начальник - это и главенство. Тогда подойдёт именно "смысловой приоритет",как тема и рема. Кто это? что о нём говорится.Приоритет всегда за подлежащим, где бы оно не стояло.

Comment: вот определение подлежащего لمبتدأ : هو اسم مرفوع مُحَدّثٌ عنه يقع في أول الجملة
мубтада это имя которое стоит в именительном падеже ,о котором идет речь и которое стоит в начале предложения

Comment: может сказать :(так как характерной особенностью подлежащего является его положение в начале предложение),но все таки не точно ,вроде бы

Comment: Я не знаю арабского, но чувствую,что что-то недоговаривается.Ещё ведь зависит, глагольное или именное предложение, почему ж только в начале? Хотя "характерной особенностью является позиция в начале" - это находка, точно передаёт то, что Вы хотите сказать, а что там на самом деле, я не знаю. Вы бы с этим лучше к переводчикам с арабского обратились или к онлайн-учебникам.

Answer (score 2):

Джон купил его уже бывшим в употреблении, за тридцать тысяч".

А если считать: "купил  бывшим в употреблении" - составное именное сказуемое со знаменательно связкой "купил", сравнить: мы расстались большими приятелями.
За тридцать тысяч - уточняющее обстоятельство.

ОТВЕТ 2. ВСё-таки не очень понятна структура предложения. Там, как было замечено,  двунаправленные отношения: купил его - купил бывшим в употреблении (для сравнения:расстались с ним - расстались приятелями). Но в любом случае надо определить состав сказуемого и его вид.Какова роль оборота "бывшим в употреблении"? Он входит в состав сказуемого?

Comment: Я нашла ответ. Это дуплексив, относящийся одновременно и к глаголу (как присвязочный компонент)и к объекту - местоимению (его):приглагольное обстоятельство (как? каким?) и определение с нарушением согласования. Это студентка филфака мне голову задурила,но теперь всё уже выяснено, мы ответили правильно, профессор похвалил.

Comment: в глагольном предложении "подлежащее" в арабском языке называется действующим лицом и всегда стоит после глагола.الفاعل. الفاعل -действующее лицо ,всегда стоит после глагола,но арабисты переводят его как подлежащее ,для сравнения. Но в арабском языке принято .что в глагольном предложении два главных члена: глагол(и как часть речи и как член предложения)и действующее лицо), а главные члены именного предложения: подлежащее и сказуемое,проблема в том ,что при обучении ,все сравнивают с русским,поэтому бесполезно искать что-то в учебниках.Спасибо Вам большое,Людмила!!!

Comment: а если до глагола будет имя оно будет подлежащим,а действующее лицо будет выражено либо видным. либо скрытым местоимением,считается,что здесь уже есть два предложения :именное начальное и глагольное ,внутри именного,которое стоит на месте именительного падежа и является сказуемым,но этого нет в учебниках, это уже можно выучить только в учебниках для арабоязычных,поэтому мне приходится все составлять самому ,а в наших учебниках идет обучение ,в котором все сопоставляется с русским языком...

Answer (score 0):

купил каким? уже бывшим в употреблении - распространенное определение

Answer (score -1):

Судя по тому, что там стоит запятая, это обстоятельства образа действия.

Точно не определение: к определению нельзя задать вопрос от сказуемого (типа "купил каким"). Определение - признак ПРЕДМЕТА. Признак ДЕЙСТВИЯ - это обстоятельство: купил как? каким образом?